# Running nuget from Visual Studio with correct sources

Tags: .net, nuget

A while ago NuGet was added to our VS solution, as so a `.nuget` folder was created with:

```
NuGet.config
NuGet.exe
NuGet.targets
```

However, when I compile the solution the config from the `.nuget` folder is not being picked up, only `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`. This is the exact opposite of what I would like to achieve. Hence the question: how is this supposed to work? Indeed when I run NuGet from outside the `.nuget` folder it doesn't pick up the config. I tried passing `-sources "path\.nuget\NuGet.config"` parameter, but this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter name for picking up NuGet config is `-configFile` (case insensitive). `nuget` is run from the script `.nuget\NuGet.targets`. To tell NuGet to run the correct config file you have to modify this script. First add a property with the path to the config file:

```
<ConfigFile>"$(NuGetToolsPath)\NuGet.config"</ConfigFile>
```

and then add the parameter the `RestoreCommand` so that it becomes:

```
<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source $(PackageSources) -configfile $(ConfigFile) -o "$(PackagesDir)"</RestoreCommand>
```

You might need to restart VS after making these changes.